# PostgreSQL: How do I avoid unwanted characters in COPY command output?

Tags: postgresql, csv, escaping, export-to-csv, delimiter

I have an array (text) (sample row) in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database like follows:

```
my_array(text)
1,112,292,19.7
```

I am exporting this text array using Postgres `COPY` command to a custom text file like this:

```
Copy
(
Select
my_array
from
my_table
Order by my_table_id
) to '~my_path/output.str' With DELIMITER ',';
```

I get the output:

```
1\,112\,292\,19.7\
```

How can I avoid these unwanted `\` in my copy command output?

Comment: You could choose another delimiter(`;` or `\t` )

Comment: Yeah. It worked! but I have other two columns (numeric) that need to be exported with this array. Thus, I would prefer COMMA as a delimiter.

Comment: You could try to add QUOTE "'"of '"' and/or force_quote(my_array)

Comment: Is this right? With DELIMITER ',' Where FORCE_QUOTE(my_array). Care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if the delimiter character (`,` in your case) is present in a string, it will be escaped (normally by prefixing it with a `\`)
- If you use a different separator (from `,`), the `,` separator doesn't have to be escaped.
- If you quote the string in the output, the `,` separator doesn't have to be escaped.

---

```
-- CREATE TABLE my_table(my_table_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, my_array text);
-- INSERT INTO my_table(my_array )VALUES ('1,112,292,19.7') ;

COPY ( SELECT my_array FROM my_table ORDER BY my_table_id)
TO '/tmp/output.str'
WITH CSV DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"'
        ;
```